# Rails Bootstrap close modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using a Bootstrap modal in a Rails app. I would like to close the modal in the view.

For instance Bootstrap documentation has:

```
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
```

I tried this:

```
<%= submit_tag 'Cancel', :type => :reset, :class => "btn btn-danger", :input_html => {data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"} %>
```

But, I get a syntax error.

I want to use the same technique to close the submit button.

I could close it in jquery, but I'd really like to close it in the form.

Thanks!

Comment: could u please post the error log :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
:input_html => {data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"}
```

Your hash is malformed. Try this:

```
:input_html => {"data-dismiss" => "modal", "aria-hidden" => "true"}
```

I believe you don't even need the `:input_html` and can just use the inner hash values right away, like so:

```
<%= submit_tag 'Cancel', :type => :reset, :class => "btn btn-danger", "data-dismiss" => "modal", "aria-hidden" => "true" %>
```